# Can we pass an object of class which has dynamically managed members via IPC?

Tags: c++, memory-management, ipc

I have a situation where I need to send an object (which has pointers to dynamically allocated objects) from one process to anther process via IPC.

Blueprint of the class is:

```
class Example
{
  std::string str;
  char *cstring;
  int value;
};
```

As you can see it has dynamically allocated data members that points to heap area mapped into that process.

If it was static object members then they are mapped in continuous memory allocation, and we can mem copy that object, right ? May be I am wrong or missing something.

Can we copy this entire object and send it over IPC, using any of the IPC mechanisms ?

Hope anyone of you can share some details how it will work or can be made to work by pointing me in right direction.

Thanks

Comment: No it's not possible, since you have pointers (directly *and* indirectly) and pointers are almost universally per-process only. Do some research about [*serializatoin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) for ways around it.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you need to serialise it into a sequential byte buffer, similar to how you might write or read say a file or over a network/internet. There are various libraries to help you with this, either with binary formats, or structured text like JSON or XML. Some may generate the boilerplate code for you to convert to and from structs or classes.

If you are using shared memory at the same virtual address, you could possibly take advantage of custom allocators to make sure STL types and other things store everything also in shared memory. I am not sure if the standard says anything much on if such use of shared memory for standard defined objects is technically compliant. I would expect `string`, `vector`, etc. to work, while things like `mutex`, `fstream`, etc. won't.

Comment: So you want me to allocate STL types in Shared memory ? Does string, vector, list etc., use any heap memory ? Can we mem copy over the IPC ?

Comment: Yes, `string` will dynamically allocate storage for the characters outside any *small string optimisation*, `list` will allocate blocks of nodes etc. So you can't just memcpy them as that would be the stored bookkeeping and *addresses* not the *contents*. With shared memory there is no `memcpy`, you would put the entire heap for those objects in shared memory.